# self.navigationController.tabBarController.selectedIndex not working

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` which containing 4 different `UIViewControllers`. 

On first tab there is a `UINavigationViewController` which contains its child `UIViewController`. without tapping the tab bar, i want to take user on second tab. For this I tried:

`self.navigationController.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;`

But it's not working.

ignore any mistake i am a newbie.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do the following, before trying to change tab:

```
UITabBarController *tab = self.tabBarController;

if (tab) {
   NSLog(@"I have a tab bar");
   [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex: 1];
}
else {
   NSLog(@"I don't have one");
}
```

Comment: Yup, I figured that out... Try the following, replace the "self.tabBarController" with "self.navigationBar.tabBarController", and see what happens on the if...

Comment: UITabBarController *tab=self.navigationController.tabBarController; is saying i dont have ... but why i didnt get it

Comment: Well @SweetJenny, without more details,it's a bit hard for me to figure it out. If you need more help, send me an email.

Comment: Oh sorry, my email sauron[dot]is[dot]alive[at]gmail[dot]com. You can contact me..

Comment: see my answer and give me reply if you not understand any thing i will help you

Comment: Jacky Boy you Rocks :) ... Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: help me too its not working for me.. my mail id is hari.777.ece@gmail.com

Answer (score 10):

if set delegate 
Try this:

```
self.selectedIndex = 1;
```

You are the tabBarController :)

Answer (score 2):

Try moving your tab switch code to **viewDidLoad**

I verified that this works on the built in Tabbed Application template project in xcode 4

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

I'd also take a look at your AppDelegate class for something along the lines of this

```
self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

If you don't see these lines anywhere then you'll want to find where else in your code the UITabBarViewController is being initialized and use that object pointer instead.

Answer (score 2):

for calling the `tabbarcontroller.selectedindex`you must have to find out the tabbarcontroller from the navigation controller if you dont use push on navigationController just use topViewController property of navigationController to get the instance of your tabBarController and assign it to UITabBarController and us the selectedIndex and this will work fine

Answer (score 1):

just try

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
```

Comment: This solution does not work when creating a tabBarController from storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

we should put follow section in viewDidAppear.

```
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
NSArray *ary = [self.tabBarController viewControllers];
    UIViewController *vc = ary[3];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:vc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are presenting a new controller (different from the one that's currently on screen) you should set the index in the completion block of the function to present your view controller. If you set it before it's presented, it may not work.

In my case I've embedded the tab controller inside a nav controller.  I present the new nav controller `newNavContoller`, and once it's presented I set the index in my tab controller `tvc`:

```
currentViewController?.presentViewController(newNavController, animated: true, completion: {tvc.selectedIndex = selectedIndex})
```