# TabBar ViewControllers in order displaying first the second item

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want to create a tab bar programmatically in a DetailViewController. I will have three ViewControllers:

1. Comments
2. Projects
3. Offers

I want to display the 3 items in this order in the TabBar, but I want to show first when I come to the DetailView the second Item in the TabBar( the one which is in the middle). How could I create my DetailViewController to manage this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using selectedIndex method you set any "view controller" using tebbar viewControllers array index.
This links also useful http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.in/2012/09/tabbed-application-doing-it.html

[self.navigationController.tabBarController.selectedIndex not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523538/self-navigationcontroller-tabbarcontroller-selectedindex-not-working)

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

UIViewController *commentsController = [[CommentsViewController alloc] init];

UIViewController *projectsController = [[ProjectsViewController alloc] init];

UIViewController *offersController = [[OffersViewController alloc] init];

self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[commentsController, projectsController, offersController];

[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create your tabBarController and just select the right index.

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2, viewController3];
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your DetailViewController inherits from UITabBarViewController

Then in inside ViewDidload:

```
self.viewControllers = @[commentsViewController, projectsViewConroller, offersViewController];
self.selectedIndex = 1; //to move to the middle
```